# Идентификатор ifstream не определен

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

Пытаюсь открыть текстовый файл, пишет идентификатор ifstream не определен(fstream подключена), может есть другой способ открыть файл.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    String fname;
    String s;
    ifstream f;     
    openFileDialog1->ShowDialog();
    fname = openFileDialog1->FileName;
    f.open(fname);
    f >> s;
    textBox1->Text = s;     
}
```

Comment: [File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8), [FileStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Это для c#, нужно именно c++

Comment: Это .NET. Язык C++/CLI именно для платформы дотнет. Там можно выбрать язык программирования (один из четырех).